# Animate div position right to left on click and close

Tags: jquery, animation, html

I have a quick question here about animating a div's position on a click event from right to left. I set up the css like this

```
#featured {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
right:-400px;
border-left:1px solid #000;
background:#fff;
padding:20px;
width:350px;
height:100%;
opacity:0.9;
```

}

Now, I might get this thing to work to animate the right position to 0px, but I'm stuck when it comes to the point of close it back again.

I basically have a div called "info". when click, #featured is being animated and has div #close in it to let #featured animate back to its original right: -400px; position.

I found other posts with the animation function, but none had it with a "close" "open" function. Since I'm still a noob when it comes to Jquery I thought I ask her. Any help woul be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you make demo here http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once:

```
$("#target").click(function () {
    var left = $('#coolDiv').offset().left;
    $("#coolDiv").css({
        left: left
    }).animate({
        "left": "0px"
    }, "slow");
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xLZV5/)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I tried this one. But what would I have to edit to "close" it once the animation was fired ?

Comment: By 'close' do you mean, closing the div or stoping the animation?

Comment: What I mean is to animate the div back to its original position. For example my div is -400px right. when the animation is fired it moves to right 400px, when hitting a button "close" it goes back to its original position of -400px. I have to implement this in order to make it work on mobile phones and using the jscrollpane.min.js on the div